# How to find row with same value in 2 columns between 2 dataframes but different values in other columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes with sample value as below :

```
df1 :
col1 cold2 cold3 cold4
a     bb    cc    d
b     aa    ee    e


df2 :
col1 cold2 cold3 col4
a    ee    ff    d
e    gg    hh    k
```

i want to find all row in 2 dataframes have same value in col1+col4 but different value in col2 or col3

output should like that :

```
df3:
col1 cold2 cold3 cold4
a     bb    cc    d
a     ee    ff    d
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) and [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html). You first have to concatenate the two dataframes, for which you have to make sure that the column names are the same.

**If your column names are actually matching** in `df1` and `df2`, do:

```
new_df = (pd.concat([df1,df2])[pd.concat([df1,df2])
                             .duplicated(subset=['col1','cold4'], keep=False)]
           .drop_duplicates(subset=['cold2', 'cold3']))
```

Which returns:

```
>>> new_df

  col1 cold2 cold3 cold4
0    a    bb    cc     d
0    a    ee    ff     d
```

**If you need to rename your columns in `df2` to match the column names of `df1`** without modifying the original dataframes, you can simply add this step:

```
concat_dfs = pd.concat([df1, df2.rename(columns={i2:i1 for i1,i2
                                         in zip(df1.columns,df2.columns)})])

new_df = (concat_dfs[concat_dfs.duplicated(subset=['col1', 'cold4'], keep=False)]
           .drop_duplicates(subset=['cold2', 'cold3']))
```

Comment: hi i was try but it keep all records although the value have not duplicated ?? 
All columns names between 2 dataframes is matched

Comment: I was try : 
`df3 = (pd.concat([df1,df2])[pd.concat([df1,df2])
                      .duplicated(subset=['EMPLOYEE_NUMBER', 'EMAIL_ADDRESS'], keep=False)].drop_duplicates(subset=['LAST_NAME','FIRST_NAME','MIDDLE_NAME','BRANCH','DEPARTMENT','LEVEL','POSITION'], keep='last', inplace=False))`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use:

```
#get all matched rows by columns
df = df1.merge(df2, on=['col1','col4'], suffixes=('','_'))
#filter for not matched  
df = df[df['col2'] != df['col3']]

#filter columns - same like df1
df1 = df[df1.columns]
#filter added new columns
df2 = df[df.columns.difference(df2.columns).union(['col1','col4'])]

#join together - rename values for align data 
df = pd.concat([df1, 
                df2.rename(columns=dict(zip(df2.columns, df1.columns)))],
                ignore_index=True)
print (df)
  col1 col2 col3 col4
0    a   bb   cc    d
1    a   ee   ff    d
```

Comment: can you explaint this `df['col2'] != df['col3']` ?? how i can use this compare with more columns ??

Comment: It is called [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), if want compare more columns there is approach first filter all columns without one and comapre with this one by `ne` - not equal and then check if all values are `True`s per rows by `all(axis=1)` - `df = df[['col3', 'col4', 'another col']].ne(df['col2'], axis=0).all(axis=1)`

Comment: @TuyenQuang - in my opinion the best should be add some sample data (in my opinion 5-8 rows for each DataFrame is nice, [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) and then add expected output. Because it seems need compare more as 2 columns, so then solution should be different

Comment: Ho Jerzael,, i imported csv file to dataframes so they have same columns name .. `'EMPLOYEE_NUMBER', 'LAST_NAME', 'FIRST_NAME', 'MIDDLE_NAME', 'BRANCH', 'DEPARTMENT', 'LEVEL', 'POSITION', 'EMAIL_ADDRESS'` is list column name. 

Values in column is text and number.. Thanks

Comment: @TuyenQuang - But I have no your data, can you edit question?

Comment: Thank you. Do you try my answer? How looks your code with real data? Is there some problem?

Comment: i don't understand this line `df = df[df['col2'] != df['col3']]`.. i tried your code but it print duplicated value on many field on 2 dataframes.