# Identifying rows shared between two Pandas DataFrames based on two columns

Tags: python, pandas

Related to: [How to find row with same value in 2 columns between 2 dataframes but different values in other columns pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50306678/how-to-find-row-with-same-value-in-2-columns-between-2-dataframes-but-different)

I have two DataFrames: `df1` and `df2`.

I would like to find all the rows in these combined DataFrames that have identical values in `'columnA'` (object) and `'columnB'` (int). These rows will have differing values in other columns I don't care about. The shape of these DataFrames also differs.

I've tried something like:

```
concat = pd.concat([df1, df2])
overlap = concat[concat.duplicated(subset=['columnA','columnB'], keep=False)]
```

But the output doesn't look right (maybe it is). Just want to check - am I missing anything?

**Edit:**

Say I wanted all the rows with the same value in `columnA` but different values in `columnB` - would this work?

```
df3 = (concat[concat.duplicated(subset=['columnA'], keep=False)]
           .drop_duplicates(subset=['columnB']))
```

Comment: Have you tried `pd.merge()`?

Comment: Regarding your edit:  are you trying to merge two df's, each with their own respective columnA and columnB?  Furthermore, if `columnA_df == columnA_df2` but `columnB_df == columnB_df2`, drop row?

Comment: Apologies - looking for separate outputs. All rows with identical values in `columnA` and `columnB`. Separately, in separate output, all rows with identical values in `columnA` but different values in `columnB`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.merge`

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=[('A','B','C'),('E','F','G'),('A','B','F')], columns=['columnA','columnB','columnC'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=[('X','Y','G'),('A','B','Y'),('A','C','F')], columns=['columnA','columnB','columnC'])

df2['columnB'] = df2['columnB'].astype(str) #convert to string

print(df1)
  columnA columnB columnC
0       A       B       C
1       E       F       G
2       A       B       F

print(df2)
 columnA columnB columnC
0       X       Y       G
1       A       B       Y
2       A       C       F
```

And then after applying `pd.merge`:

```
df_m = pd.merge(df1,df2,how='inner',on='columnA')

----
df_m
  columnA columnB_x columnC_x columnB_y columnC_y
0       A         B         C         B         Y
1       A         B         C         C         F
2       A         B         F         B         Y
3       A         B         F         C         F
```

Regarding your edit, try this:

```
df_final = df_m[df_m['columnB_x'] != df_m['columnB_y']]

------
print(df_final)
  columnA columnB_x columnC_x columnB_y columnC_y
1       A         B         C         C         F
3       A         B         F         C         F
```

Comment: Will update original post with datatypes - `ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat`

Comment: Is columnA a string object?

Comment: ok final update complete.  please vote as answer if this is sufficient.